# python: how to transfer 2dim matrix to 1dim according to the 2dim contents

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2dim numpy array，content in it is like a combination format of `(-1,0,1)` and `(0,1,2,3,4)`

now I want to assign the different combination into a 1dim matrix. for example, the `[-1,0]` transfer to 1 `[-1,1]` transfer to 2, and the final result will be a 1-15 1-dim matrix.

due to my data is very big,  the for circulation with low efficiency is not appropriate. Thus I want to `np.where` to realize the function.

Supposed the 2-dim data is represented as `a`, and the shape is `(100,2)`

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

dic =  set(itertools.product([-1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))

for key,value in enumerate():
    a[np.where(a==[-1,0])[0]]=key
```

but the output of the where will match two times with one discrimination, and the assignment will cover the front data. and the result will still be `(100,0)` with cover data.

so how can I realize my ideas? I mean rapid with little computation.
or is there another way to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I have already solved this problem now.

```
import itertools
dic = (set(itertools.product([-1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])))
for key,values in enumerate(dic):
    address = np.where(a==values)[0]
    a[np.delete(address,np.unique(address,return_index=True)[1])]=key
one_dim_result = a[:,0]
```

if there are some greater methods, plz share to me. thanks